# Geeting RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "sourceStart" is out of range. It must be <= 9. Received 13

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ubuntu

I am trying to run the node using nodemon and am getting this error in the ubuntu server machine(20.0.2).

RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "sourceStart" is out of range. It must be <= 9. Received 13
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at _copy (node:buffer:235:11)
at Buffer.copy (node:buffer:776:12)
at Parser.parseBuffer (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:272:16)
at HandshakeInitializationPacket.parse (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/packets/HandshakeInitializationPacket.js:34:37)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:272:12)
at Parser._parsePacket (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:433:10)
at Parser.write (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket. (/home/ubuntu/cryztal_backend/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:88:28) {
code: 'ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

ormConfig
{
"type": "mysql",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 33060,
"username": "root",
"password": "root",
"database": "cryztal_dev",
"synchronize": true,
"logging": false,
"migrationsTableName": "migrations",
"entities": ["src/entity/**/*.ts"],
"migrations": ["src/migration/**/*.ts"],
"subscribers": ["src/subscriber/**/*.ts"],
"cli": {
"entitiesDir": "src/entity",
"migrationsDir": "src/migration",
"subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
}
}

datasource.ts

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
type: 'mysql',
host: 'localhost',
port: 33060,
username: 'root',
password: 'root',
database: 'cryztal_dev',
synchronize: true,
logging: false,
entities: [
User,
PRIMARY.PARTNER.Partner,
PRIMARY.DEALS.Deals,
PRIMARY.ADMIN.Admin,
CATEGORY_MASTER.CategoryMaster,
PRIVACY.PrivacyPolicy,
SUBCATEGORY.SubCategoryMater,
],
migrations: [],
subscribers: [],
});

Comment: Are you sure you want port 33060 and not 3306? https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-nodejs is not https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Comment: @Ry- yes I am sure...
For Ubuntu server machines SQL services run on 33060 I have checked It.
And also found the solution

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error.
When I initially did the setup and while running the Nodejs.
The problem is I didn't create the DB which was configured in ORMconfig.js.

SO please make sure the DB setup is done correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).